# WPF Event Trigger Add BlurEffect

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles

I want to add a blur effect to my window in some cases so I wrote a custom window style.
-I wrote a custom style because I have buttons in front of the blur effect that will get visible when the blur effect is applied, but the buttons should not get blurred.

I used the following code to apply blur:

```
<AdornerDecorator.Effect>
  <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding Path=(local:StandardWindowEventHandler.LockedOverlayVisibility),
                       Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBlurConverter}}"
              KernelType="Gaussian" />
</AdornerDecorator.Effect>
```

**this worked fine but** the GPU is at ~50% when I'm in my TreeView even when radius is 0.
Without blur effect it is at like 2%. Now I don't want to set the radius any more, but the whole blur effect instead.

I have tried this:

```
<AdornerDecorator.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:StandardWindowEventHandler.LockedOverlayVisibility)}"
                 Value="Visible">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_WindowAdornerDecorator"
                Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <BlurEffect Radius="10" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</AdornerDecorator.Triggers>
```

Unfortunately Triggers shall be Event triggers. If I make the event trigger change the radius I've won nothing, **is there any possibility to add the blur effect via event trigger?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
<Grid x:Name="Root_Grid"
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"
                    SourceName="Button1">
        <window:SetBlurEffectAction />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"
                    SourceName="Button2">
        <window:SetBlurEffectAction />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<AdornerDecorator ClipToBounds="True"
                  x:Name="PART_WindowAdornerDecorator">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_RootContentPresenter"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ActualWindowTemplate}"
                      dxr:RibbonControlHelper.IsAutoHide="{TemplateBinding RibbonAutoHideMode}"
                      dxr:RibbonControlHelper.DisplayShowModeSelector="{TemplateBinding DisplayShowModeSelector}" />
</AdornerDecorator>
```

The Root_Grid is the parent of the AdornerDecorator as you can see.
Button1 and Button2 are some grandchildren of the Root_Grid.

```
public class SetBlurEffectAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject> {
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter) {
        var e = parameter as RoutedEventArgs;
        // OriginalSource is one of the buttons
        var parent = e?.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        // get Grid (parent of AdornerDecorator)
        while(true) {
            if(parent == null) {
                return;
            }
            var grid = parent as Grid;
            if("Root_Grid".Equals(grid?.Name)) {
                break;
            }
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }
        // apply blur to this AdornerDecorator
        var deco = ((Grid)parent).GetElementByName("PART_WindowAdornerDecorator") as AdornerDecorator;
        if(deco == null) {
            return;
        }
        // != collapsed because the property is not updated yet
        if(StandardWindowEventHandler.LockedOverlayVisibility != Visibility.Collapsed) {
            deco.Effect = null;
        } else {
            deco.Effect = new BlurEffect {
                KernelType = KernelType.Gaussian,
                Radius = 7
            };
        }
    }
}
```

StandardWindowEventHandler.LockedOverlayVisibility is a static Property that gets updated when one of the buttons is pressed.